# Inside of a ternary php script how do i concatenate a second variable into my string?

Tags: php

Before style="style="color: ' . $rx_event_colors . '" I want to add the $ima variable. it's just a variable with an image inside of the string. Additionally, if you think i would benefit from just adding the

```
 if(!empty($ins_event))
            {
            echo "<tr><td>&nbsp; <a href='". matry::here(array('event_id'=>$ins_event['id'])) . "'" . 
            ( $ins_event['status'] == 2 ? ' style="color: ' . $rx_event_colors . '">Completed Insurance Event' : '>Active Insurance Event') . "</a></td></tr>";     

            }
```

I've tried:

```
? ' $ima, style="style="color: ' . $rx_event_colors . '"
                      style="style="color: ' . $ima, $rx_event_colors . '"
                      style="style="color: ' . ($ima), $rx_event_colors . '"
                      style="style="color: ' . ($ima), ($rx_event_colors) . '"
```

with no avail.

Comment: .(dot) not ,(comma) in the concatanator in php

Comment: Why are you so desperate to use the ternary operator. It makes no sense if the code becomes unintelligible and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming **$ima** is a string. To concatenate strings, use the "."

So in the first part of your ternary, if you'd like to add **$ima**, simply do this:

```
' style="color: ' . $ima . $rx_event_colors . '">Completed Insurance Event'
```

However, I'm confused when you say "[$ima] just a variable with an image inside of the string". Does **$ima** contain the path to the image itself? If so, it belongs in the SRC attribute of the img tag, not inside the STYLE attribute.

***UPDATE:***

Because **$ima** contained the entire img tag, it doesn't belong in the style atrribute. See:

```
' style="color: ' . $rx_event_colors . '">' . $ima . 'Completed Insurance Event'
```

Comment: Sorry, yes it contains the path as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what $ima has in it exactly?

Comment: $ima = "<img src='/flet/check-icon.gif'>";

Comment: Oh! The **$ima** variable contains the entire img tag. If this is the case, then you cannot place **$ima** inside of the attribute of another tag.

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is add the image before the stylized words (as some sort of bullet point).


Try this:
`' style="color: ' . $rx_event_colors . '">' . $ima . 'Completed Insurance Event'`


This way **$ima** is INSIDE the a tag which you are styling and not inside its style attribute.

Comment: it worked.. mark that as the answer and i'll give you the check. Thank you very much.   'style="color: ' . $rx_event_colors . '">' . $ima . 'Completed Insurance Event' : '>Active Insurance Event')

Comment: I have updated my answer (this comment's parent) to reflect the final answer. You can give that answer the check, if you choose!